# Create automated backups for Access DBs in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ms-access, backup

I have an application written in C# WinForms that uses Access DBs with *.temx extension.
I would like to create automated backups for the DBs inside the application.

How can I create automated backups in C# for Access DBs?

Note: I don't want to install any other application (like Cobian for ex.) for creating backups and I need the backups stored locally. My application opens only one DB at a time.

Comment: Your 'database' is just a file...why not simply create a copy with some decent name using File-api?

Comment: @SanchoPanza Should I use File.Copy to create the backups? When should I create the backups, after opening the file or after closing the file, because the app doesn't run all the time in the background? (The save in the database is instant for every operation.)

Comment: @SanchoPanza I'm asking this, because one of my clients overwritten the DB by mistake - instead of opening the file, he clicked on new file and approved overwrite.

Comment: IMO the 'mistake' was not done by your client, but by your app enabling your client to overwrite data. Your app should clearly prevent this. Duplicating a file can be done in various ways - File.Copy being one of them. Your question on when to do the backup can not be answered without further details and entirely depends on your use-case